# Confusion about audacity macro export/noise reduction

Tags: audacity

Im a bit confused about how to macro export(as WAV in this case)

My over arching goal is to apply noise reduction across multiple files.
According the the instructions this is done(as a macro) by creating a file containing only the sample clip to apply as reduction, naming it 000(so its first) andd applying it to the files.

When i tried this in a macro it says it cant import AUP3 format, use file > open instead.
So i figured i needed to export the files to WAV first then apply the noise reduction.

So when i tried export as WAV by macro, it says the same thing "connot import AUP3 files"
I see this is mentioned in the instructions too, but im still confused.

When I save a audacity recording its in AUP3 file. so this is the file type that will usually need to be exported. But I cant open this kind of file for use in macros? Even the export macro?

Brand new, so no doubt im missing something obvious.

Any one knoe how to do this?

Comment: Could you add a link to the instructions you're using?

Answer (score 3):

`AUP3` is for *projects*, not audio files. The docs explicitly state that macros can't be applied over AUP3 files without custom scripting ([search for AUP3 on this page](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/apply_macro.html)). This includes the noise profile sample you have sorted first on the filesystem. So you'll need to export each project you wish to apply the macro to, as an audio file (WAV, or whatever you like), and then use those as the import target for your macro. You said you exported all your target audio as WAVs, so my guess is that this error is because your noise profile was still a project, not an audio file. But:

Importantly, you don't really need a noise profile file; if you use your noisy audio to get a Noise Profile, that hangs around until you get a new one or close Audacity. So there's no need to save anything out to disk, you can run your macro and it will work with that noise profile.

Some references:
Make sure you [double check this section](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/apply_macro.html#files) to be sure you understand how batch processing works and its tradeoffs. Additionally take a look at the section on macros in the [noise reduction documentation](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/noise_reduction.html).